# definition of a fiber bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

I came across the definition of a fiber bundle in May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" (http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf, Chapter 7, section 4). There were two main parts to the definition used. The first part mentioned homeomorphisms $ \phi: U \times F \rightarrow p^{-1}(U)$ such that $ p \phi = \pi_1$, where $F$ is a fixed topological space and and $U$ is an open set in a countable open cover of $E$.

After that, it is claimed that there are continuous maps $\lambda_U: B \rightarrow I$ such that $\lambda_U^{-1}(0, -1] = U$ and the cover is locally finite.

Are the conditions in the second part  of the definition implied by the first, or are they just additional conditions for a "well chosen" open cover? If they are implied by the first part, why is that the case?

Comment: The second is a condition on a manifold, the existence of a decomposition of unity, adapted to the atlas of the manifold.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean...could you clarify what this means?

Comment: There is a countable atlas $A$ of charts $U$ that are open subsets of $B$ and with the property that for any $x\in B$ there is only a finite number of charts $U\in A$ with $x\in U$. Then a standard construction is to prove the existence of a [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity), a family of scalar functions $λ_U:B\to [0,1]$ with support $\text{supp}λ_U\subset U$ and $\sum_{U: x\in U\in A}  λ_U(x)=1$. This partition of unity is used, among other things, to extend local constructions to the full manifold or fibre bundle.